# How to access ng-repeat item object into directive and child scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using `ng-repeat` in a custom element directive. Two similar questions:

1. How do I access the enumerated item from the directive's `link` handler?
2. How do I access the enumerated item from the item's controller? In my example, in `MyItemCtrl`, in `$scope.myItemClicked`.

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/64PiskrR7aGFKfrSq1up?p=preview

My main HTML looks like this:

```
<my-item ng-repeat="myItem in myArray"></my-item>
```

The `myItem` directive is created like this:

```
app.directive('myItem', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myItemTemplate.html',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {

      $('#log').append('Directive link phase. How can I access myItem here?\n');

    }
  };
});
```

That template, `myItemTemplate.html`, is:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="myItemClicked()" ng-controller="MyItemCtrl">
  Click here to examine: {{myItem}}<br />
</a>
```

And my child controller is:

```
app.controller('MyItemCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myItemClicked = function()
  {
    $('#log').append('myItemClicked(). How do I access myItem here without passing it as an argument?\n');
  };

});
```

I realize I can pass `myItem` as a function parameter, so changing:

```
ng-click="myItemClicked()"
```

to

```
ng-click="myItemClicked(myItem)
```

But this seems really inelegant; I'm sure there's a better way. Right?

Comment: Doing `console.log($scope.myItem);` right above yielded the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller add a property to store the selected item:

```
$scope.itemClicked = {};
```

In the link function, in your directive, you can get the selected item from the element:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.itemClicked = element;
}
```

I have updated the plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YtHePqSGZk9ja40sygG9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Inside of controller `this` points to current scope object. So in your case you can do this:

```
$scope.myItemClicked = function() {
    $('#log').append(this.myItem);
};
```

Sidenote, performing DOM manipulations in controller is not very good practice.

Comment: You can also just use `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$index`, like this:

```
  <my-item item='{{myArray[$index]}}' ng-repeat="myItem in myArray">
  </my-item>
```

And then get attribute 'item' value in directive code:
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
app.directive('myItem', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'myItemTemplate.html',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {

      $('#log').append($attributes['item']);

    }
  };
});
```